# Function parameters out of range in function

Tags: python

For a class project I have to make a hangman game. Following it's guidelines I have gotten this code:

```
def hangman(guessed, secret):
  word = ""
  wrongLetters = 0
  checkLetter = 0
  compareLetter = 0
  for i in range(len(secret)):
      if secret[checkLetter] == guessed[compareLetter]:
            word += guessed[compareLetter]
          compareLetter = 0
          checkLetter += 1
      elif secret[checkLetter] != guessed[compareLetter]:
          compareLetter += 1
          for i in range(len(secret) - 1):
              if secret[checkLetter] == guessed[compareLetter]:
                  word += guessed[checkLetter]
                  break
              elif secret[checkLetter] != guessed[compareLetter]:
                  compareLetter += 1
                  wrongLetters += 1
              elif wrongLetters == len(secret):
                  word += "-"
                  wrongLetters = 0
                  checkLetter += 1
                  compareLetter = 0
  print(word)
```

My issue is that it tells me that `if secret[checkLetter] == guessed[compareLetter]:` under the second `for` statement is out of range of the string index. I believe it is because my function parameters are local. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: how are you passing `secret` as argument to your function?

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing your code with various inputs, what I found out is that the error occurs when value of variable `compareLetter` exceeds length of `guessed`.
Looks like there is some problem in the logic!!

I tried with `hangman('banana', 'apple')`
Here is the how the value of `checkLetter` and `compareLetter` is changing:

```
0 1
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 6
```

Hope you understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more issues than I'm seeing at first glance, but here goes.

1) In the second for loop you will NEVER get to the last elif case.

2) You don't reset compareLetter when you get to the end of the list of guessed letters. Which means that eventually, it CAN get larger than than the length of 'guessed' which is what is causing your exception.

3) You have named both of your for loop iterators i. And you don't use them ever.

4) Your for loops go through the length of secret twice, nested. And again, you don't use the iterators.

As eiram_mahera pointed out, your codes logic is flawed. Look at what you are doing each loop, and compare that to what you WANT to be doing each loop. They are not the same thing.